# My userdata script is not getting parameters from ssm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

my user data script is set to pull a parameter out of System Manager parameter store on a windows instance, it has the correct permissions but the script is not performing as expected;

```
<powershell>
choco install -y awscli
choco install -y jq
aws ssm get-parameter --name myParam --output json | jq -r .Parameter.Value | New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "myParam" -ItemType "file"
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

However, when booting up the instance the file appears in C:\ drive but it is empty, so the issue is running the was ssm get-parameter command. I have ran the command after booting the windows instance and it pulls the parameter down correctly, but during user data, it doesn't.

Anyone got any ideas why it might not be working?

Comment: How have you provided IAM credentials for the command to use? For example, is it via a credentials file, or via an IAM Role assigned to the instance?

Comment: Hi, the IAM role is assigned in a Cloudformation template

Comment: What is the contents of `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log`? See: [Run commands on your Windows instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

Comment: I think I've identified the issue, I think choco install is being run then the rest of the user data script is being run before the packages have finished installing. I have tried using the  Start-Process -Wait command to no avail so far. The logs show that when running "aws ssm" the command "aws" is not found which indicates it is trying to do it before the package has installed.